# How does deja-dup react to whole folders being moved?

Tags: backup, deja-dup

Does deja-dup have some mechanism to detect when I've moved a complete folder into a new subfolder?
Or will it copy all the files in the folder again?

I'm talking about folders that contain some 100 GB of data, so if I do something the wrong way several times, my backup drive could easily run out of space without really needing to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

duplicity, which Déjà Dup is built upon on, does not have any such intelligence. Hence any moved or renamed files will be treated as new files.

Comment: Nice answer, but... ewww! (about duplicity's lack of such feature). The same goes for rsync, which is duplicity's "backbone"?

Comment: Well, duplicity does use librsync for deltas, but that is hardly the same thing as what is conventionally meant by running rsync.

Comment: That sucks, at least for one of my backup profiles: I constantly re-organize my music and movies collection. Also documents, work projects, etc. The files themselves rarely change, but their name and location may vary drastically.